# Sequentually unpickle large files asynchronously

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, pickle

I have a directory of Pickled lists which I would like to load sequentially, use as part of an operation, and then discard. The files are around 0.75 - 2GB each when pickled and I can load a number in memory at any one time, although nowhere near all of them. Each pickled file represents one day of data.

Currently, the unpickling process consumes a substantial proportion of the runtime of the program. My proposed solution is to load the first file and, whilst the operation is running on this file, asynchronously load the next file in the list.

I have thought of two ways I could do this: 1) Threading and 2) Asyncio. I have tried both of these but neither has seemed to work. Below is my (attempted) implementation of a Threading-based solution.

```
import os
import threading
import pickle

class DataSource:
    def __init__(self, folder):
        self.folder = folder
        self.next_file = None

    def get(self):
        if self.next_file is None:
            self.load_file()
        data = self.next_file
    
        io_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.load_file, daemon=True)
        io_thread.start()

        return data

    def get_next_file(self):
        for filename in sorted(os.listdir(self.folder)):
            yield self.folder + filename

    def load_file(self):
        self.next_file = pickle.load(open(next(self.get_next_file()), "rb"))
```

The main program will call *DataSource().get()* to retrieve each file. The first time it is loaded, *load_file()* will load the file into *next_file* where it will be stored. Then, the thread *io_thread* should load each successive file into *next_file* to be returned via *get()* as needed.

The thread that is launched does appear to do some work (it consumes a vast amount of RAM, ~60GB) however it does not appear to update *next_file*.

Could someone suggest why this doesn't work? And, additionally, if there is a better way to achieve this result?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`DataSource().get()` seems to be your first problem: that means you create a new instance of the DataSource class always, and only ever get to load the first file, because you never call the same DataSource object instance again so that you'd proceed to the next file. Maybe you mean to do along the lines of:

```
datasource = DataSource()
while datasource.not_done():
    datasource.get()
```

It would be useful to share the full code, and preferrably on repl.it or somewhere where it can be executed.

Also, if you want better performance, I might be worthwhile to look into the multiprocessing module, as Python blocks some operations with the global interpreter lock (GIL) so that only one thread runs at a time, even when you have multiple CPU cores. That might not be a problem though in your case as reading from disk is probably the bottleneck, I'd guess Python releases the lock while executing underlying native code to read from filesystem.

I'm also curious about how you could use asyncio for pickles .. I guess you read the pickle to mem from a file first, and then unpickle when it's done, while doing other processing during the loading. That seems like it could work nicely.

Finally, I'd add debug prints to see what's going on.

Update: Next problem seems to be that you are using the get_next_file generator wrongly. There you create a new generator each time with self.get_next_file(), so you only ever load the first file. You should only create the generator once and then call next() on it. Maybe this helps to understand, is also on replit:

```
def get_next_file():
        for filename in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
            yield filename

for n in get_next_file():
  print(n)

print("---")

print(next(get_next_file()))
print(next(get_next_file()))
print(next(get_next_file()))

print("---")

gen = get_next_file()
print(gen)
print(next(gen))
print(next(gen))
print(next(gen))
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
---
a
a
a
---
<generator object get_next_file at 0x7ff4757f6cf0>
a
b
c
```

https://repl.it/@ToniAlatalo/PythonYieldNext#main.py

Again, debug prints would help you see what's going on, what file you are loading when etc.

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear. I'm not creating a new DataSource each time, I just used that as an example. The actual code I am testing with is:`d = DataSource(FOLDER_LOCATION)
print(d.get()[0]["timestamp"])
time.sleep(60)
print(d.get()[0]["timestamp"])`. I will take a look at multiprocessing and see if that works and if not I will upload the full code. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, well that was bad indeed to put code in the question that you don't actually run. I think I found another bug, see the update in the answer. You don't need multiprocessing if you process the data one by one, loading on the background with async or threads is fine for that (I'd probably use async). Multiprocessing is I think really necessary in this case only if you can't update async loading during your processing, or if you want to process multiple files serially utilizing multiple cores.